# Browser width query - activate viewport

Tags: javascript, css, viewport, responsive

I'm searching for a solution to add the viewport-meta tag only on devices, which screen width is bigger than 680px. If the screen is small than 680px,the responsive style file should be enable instead.

I tried it this way inside the  section, but on my iPhone this shows me the viewport settings as well, instead the responsive style.

```
<script>
if ($(window).width() < 680) {   
alert("Smartphone Device");
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive.css" />');
}
else {
 document.write('
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=1100" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">');
}
</script>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had an JavaScript error. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if ($(window).width() < 680) {   
alert("Smartphone Device");
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive.css" />');
}
else {
 $('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">','<meta name="viewport" content="width=1100" />','<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">');
 alert("Desktop");
}

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sadly I get the altert "Desktop" on both devices. Also for these, which are under 680px width.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. This solution works fine for me:

```
if (matchMedia) {
    var mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 680px)");
    mq.addListener(WidthChange);
    WidthChange(mq);
}

function WidthChange(mq) {
    if (mq.matches) {
        alert("Desktop");
        $('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=1100px" />');
    } else {
        alert("Smartphone Device");

        $('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />');
    }

}
```